# Allowing Adobe Updater to run for restricted User

Tags: windows-7, updates

At the moment we have 34 laptops running a single image, Windows 7, that we hand out to staff on long term loan.
The Users are locked down quite tightly as to what they can do. They cannot install any software. However they can run Microsoft updates and the AV updates also run.
One problem we have run into is that the Users are unable to update the Adobe suite of products that we provide on the laptops.
Is there any configuration we can set up to allow these updaters to run. I have looked into [AppLocker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560656(WS.10).aspx) but this only seems to allow me to restrict and allow certain software to run and that isn't quite what I want.

Is there a way to allow Restricted Users to install Adobe Updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be through Task Scheduler. There you can assign the SYSTEM user rights on the TASK, so the TASK triggered will run by SYSTEM user and NOT the Standard User in the machine.

-Hope this helps. If you have any other questions, let me know.

Comment: How would you assign the task to only run when there was updates available though? I was more hoping of an expection that could be applied to the program / publisher that would allow users to run the updates as they chose. But I will try out your suggestion now. Thansk for the quick answer

Comment: No problem. It would be hard to give the users permissions to do something like that. I have never tried doing that before. I would try checking in the group policies to see if there is a setting for it.

Comment: Yeah, I like your answer, technically it is a way to allow Restricted Users to install Adobe Updates? So It gets a +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Building on David's answer: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html

you don't have to have the task run itself you can create a shortcut.

another approach is to put the adobe updater inside of a servifythis executable and make it a system service...that way the update watchdog isn't run as local user, but as a service.  the actions performed on it's behalf might then become a system service as well...